# WebStorm unresolved variable warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm

I use WebStorm for React JS and I'm getting this 'Unresolved variable warning' by all props.

[image]

But everything works without problems, language is defined, it exists. 
Code works, I don't have any issues with my app.

This is what I have inside `Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries`

[image]

Any idea how to avoid those warnings?

**UPDATE**

Code example where that happens. First parent component :

```
import ExpirationTimer from '../../common/expirationTimer';

export default class ListView extends React.Component {
    render (){
        const language = this.props.language;
        let expirationDate = "Wed May 10 2017 15:58:59 GMT+0200";

        return (
            <div>
                <ExpirationTimer expirationDate={expirationDate} language={language}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Where language is an object `{lowestPrice: "Lowest price", mileage: "Mileage", ....}`

And then the component where I try to get those props, it works, but I get warning that they are unresolved :

```
 export default class ExpirationTimer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {                
            expirationDate: this.props.expirationDate // Here I get the warning
        };
    }

    render(){
        let language = this.props.language; // Here I get the warning


        return (
            <div>
                .....
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste in a small snippet of code that this is happening on so I can recreate the file in webstorm and see what I see in mine?

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue that still hasn't been resolved yet :(

Comment: to me, the errors go away when I disable `react-definitely typed` in Libraries

Comment: note that completion/resolving only works for components with explicit `propTypes` declaration only - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18816#comment=27-1415798

Answer (score 3):

use destructuring assignment: 
`let {language} = this.props` 
instead `let language = this.props.language;`